# how to perform a mthematical loop in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a total price and list of items with quantity. I want to calculate each item price based on that data.

for example if : total price  is `200`
and I have:

```
item name    quantity
item_a         100
item_b         2
```

a possible solution is:

```
item name    quantity   price
item_a         100       1
item_b         2        50
```

because:

```
100 * 1 + 2 * 50 = 200
```

This is very simple to do with a loop and diversion with Python,java or any programming language...

I'm having trouble to apply this logic to Postgresql query.

I have:
`shipment` table:

```
shipmnetid  price
    5        200
    7         10
```

`shipmentitems` table:

```
siid  shipmentid   itemid qty
1         5         700   100
2         5         701   2
3         7          1
```

I need to write a query that will generate (for `shipmentid=5`):

```
itemid quantity price
 700      100     1
 701       2      50
```

Price is not saved in table, each run of the query can generate diffrent prices... (or order it by siid  and then it will always be same values)

I know this sounds wierd, this is about very old items that their price is unknown, so I only have the total value of the shipment and I need to "rebuid" the item prices.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please show us the "simple loop" in Python that can do this. :)

Comment: That looks like a [linear diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#One_equation), and SQL doesn't seem to be a good tool for this.

Comment: Aren't there numerous theoretical possibilities?  For example, the price on item 700 could have been 0.5, and the price on item 701 could be 75, and it would still come up with 200.  It looks sort of like an NP complete problem

Comment: I'm not looking for all solutions or best solution.. i'm looking for any solution. It can be always the same one.

Comment: I guess you could generate a temp table with all possible prices, cross join that on orders and sum up the order quantities times possible price.  Keep anything that satisfies your orders.  Then pick out the ones that satisfy all orders (using a group by, count, etc).  I would post this as an answer, but I don't know enough postgresql to do it (SqlServer syntax sure, but Postgres, nope).  Also, no idea how long it would take to run something like this.  There is certainly a better linear algebra solution to this, but that is probably a hard problem too because of data size.

Comment: For two positions you will have `~(total-1)` combinations. For three positions it will be `~(total-2)^2` combinations and so on, in general, `~(total-positions)^positions` (total is in cents). IMO it is not a truly realistic task.

Comment: Probably the best option is a plpython function.

Comment: @JakubKania which technology to use is not a substantial part of the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say in the comments, any solution is good then just take the average price:

```
select shipmentid, itemid, qty, price::real / total_shipment_qty as price
from
    shipment s
    inner join (
        select
            shipmentid,
            itemid,
            qty,
            sum(qty) over(partition by shipmentid) as total_shipment_qty
        from shipmentitems
    ) i using (shipmentid)
;
 shipmentid | itemid | qty |      price       
------------+--------+-----+------------------
          5 |    700 | 100 | 1.96078431372549
          5 |    701 |   2 | 1.96078431372549
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f8168/1